# Input Output errors on disk drives

Tags: disk, io

I am completely new to the ins and outs of linux. I am trying to check my drives by running an exerciser software, `blast`, that checks the read and write capabilities. I run write verify loop on the drives with max data of 200 bytes and 2 iterations. Frustratingly I keep on running into this error for certain specific drives `/dev/sdh` and `/dev/sdi` where it shows an error:

```
Error code 5 detected on /dev/sdh/ EIO I/O Error
```

When I run `fdisk -l`. The drives mention above does not even show. It goes from `/dev/sdg` to `/dev/sdj`. Is there anything I can do to fix this or some other commands I can run or things I can read/learn so I can do some further investigating.

Comment: question edited, please let me know if there are other things to run to get better information for me to provide

Comment: Exerciser is called blast. I run write verify loop on the drives with max data of 200 bytes and 2 iterations.  About 25 drives. Output is /dev/sd[LETTER] so for `ls /dev/sdh` it will output `/dev/sdh` for `ls -l ___` `brw-rw----.  1 root disk    8, DATE  sdh`

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -ld /dev/sd?` to your question

Comment: Looks like the devices that would be in the `sdh` and `sdi` slots may be broken so they won't complete their initial set-up. Check the output of `dmesg` for errors related to those disks; the outputs of `lsblk` and/or `lsscsi` may help in identifying the disks in question, possibly by exclusion. `smartctl -a /dev/sdh` and `smartctl -a /dev/sdi` might be informative too.

Comment: ls -ld returns the same output as ls -l. 
For dmesg: 
`blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdi, sector 0
 Buffer I/O error on dev sdi, logical block 0, async page read
sd 1:0:7:0: [sdi] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 1:0:7:0: [sdi] Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] [descriptor] 
sd 1:0:7:0: [sdi] Add. Sense: Logical block reference tag check failed
sd 1:0:7:0: [sdi] CDB: Read(32)
` among many other errors related to sdh and sdi, seems like mainly repeats though

Answer (score 1):

You have a hardware problem, either in that disk or the controller. It is disconnecting and reconnecting when you ask it to do things.

It might be possible to get further clues from `smartctl -a` but basically your disk sounds broken.

Comment: oh i see. Thank you for your response